# Django ManyToMany Field in form - unnecessary database calls?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-orm

In a django form that has a manyToMany field - is there a database call to retrieve each object in the list when you're adding a new entry? Is this necessary/ wasteful?

For example:

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    likes = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Videos.objects.all())

....

the form is submitted with a list of project id's. within the clean() method likes becomes a list of Video objects. However you can do:

self.instance.likes.add() ...without ever having to get the objects.

...

is it wasteful that the objects are being retrieved first before updating the relationship? if not, why?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that every time you save the form, it would be evaluating the queryset you passed it to check that each ID is within that queryset. if you wish to optimize the behavior, try subclassing ModelMultipleChoiceField and removing the checks/making them more streamlined.